# Why is my array not including prexisting drop down values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to cut a master file. Columns P and R have data in some rows, and some do not. I want to tell VBA, if there's data in that row, do not create a drop down list, but if there is no data, then create a drop down option for the manager.

How would I alter my data validation module to say `if there is data already in there, ignore creating a drop down, but create a drop down option for any blank cells in those two columns`

Here is my original module:

```
Sub DataValidation()

    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="Yes - Regularly Works Eligible Shift,No - Does Not Regularly Work Eligible Shift"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

    With Range("R2:R" & lastrow).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="8%,10%,12%,15%"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code such as the following to target *only* those blank cells:

```
Sub DataValidation()

    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes - Regularly Works Eligible Shift,No - Does Not Regularly Work Eligible Shift"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

    With Range("R2:R" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="8%,10%,12%,15%"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: There is one error to trap for. If the entire `Range("P2:P" & lastRow)` is blank, then the code will return an error. This is because the `.SpecialCells` method call returns a Range object, excepting at least 1 cell.

One work around is to use error handling, and store the range into a variable. If all of the cells are blank, then they all need validation. Otherwise, only validate those cells that are blank (if you *truly* never foresee this happening, then you can skip this). Code below:

```
Sub DataValidation()
    Dim rng As Range

    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("P2:P" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes - Regularly Works Eligible Shift,No - Does Not Regularly Work Eligible Shift"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    Else
        With rng.Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes - Regularly Works Eligible Shift,No - Does Not Regularly Work Eligible Shift"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    End If

    'Reset to reuse with the R column
    Set rng = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("R2:R" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        With Range("R2:R" & lastrow).Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="8%,10%,12%,15%"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    Else
        With rng.Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="8%,10%,12%,15%"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Says `Runtime error 1004 - No Cell Were Found` and is highlighting the first `With` Statement

Comment: is there something I can replace the `.IgnoreBlank = True` part and have it just ignore cells with data in there?

Comment: @nicklanta See my edit to the code. The error was being thrown because the entire range was blank. You actually left your comment while I was in the middle of editing my post.

Comment: Ok so this worked perfectly, here's one other question: Say a cell has data in it, is there a way to keep that data, but also allow it to be changed again via drop down? Currently, this only allows blank cells to have a drop down, and doesn't allow drop down changes to be made to preexisting data

Comment: is that addition possible?

Comment: @nicklanta You can simply run the code without checking for blank cells. Starting with the line `With Range("P2:P" & lastrow).Validation` through the `End With` and then repeat it for column R. This will add validation to the cells, even if they have data. Once the user clicks the dropdown, it will allow them to make the change. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
With Range("I1:I" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="8%,10%,12%,15%"
 .IgnoreBlank = True
 .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Comment: Says `Runtime error 1004 - No Cell Were Found` and is highlighting the line `With.Special Cells` line